# Going to Python from R, what's the python equivalent of a data frame?

Tags: python, r

I'm familiar with the R data holders like vectors, dataframe, etc. but need to do some text analysis and it seems like python has some good setups for doing so.  My question is where can I find an explanation of how python holds data.

Specifically I have a data set in a tab-separated file where the text is in the 3rd column and the scoring of the data that I need is in the 4th column.

```
id1            id2            text                             score
123            889     "This is the text I need to read..."      88
234            778     "This is the text I need to read..."      78
345            667     "This is the text I need to read..."      91
```

In R I'd just load it into a data frame named `df1` and when I wanted to call a column I'd use df1$text or `df1[,3]`  and if I wanted a specific cell I could use `df1[1,3]`.

I am getting a feel for how to read data into python but not how to deal with table like structures.

How would you suggest working with this for a python newbie?

Comment: Python has no equivalent to the data frame

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What about that [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) stuff? Isn't that (intended to be) close?

Comment: @joran That's 3rd party. I suppose I meant there is nothing built in in the way that the R data frame is built in.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look at the [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) object in the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

Answer (score 15):

Mr Ullrich's answer of using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library is the closest approach to the R data frame.  However, you can get extremely similar functionality using the [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), with the data type set to `object` if necessary.  Newer versions of numpy have [field name capabilities](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) similar to a `data.frame`, its indexing is actually somewhat more powerful than R's, and its ability to contain objects goes well beyond what R can do.

I use both R and numpy, depending on the task at hand.  R is way better with formulas and built-in statistics.  The Python code is more maintainable and easier to hook up to other systems.

*Edited: added note that numpy now has field name capabilities*

Comment: R's `data.frame` can contain `list` columns. Each element of a `list` column can be anything you like including data objects, functions, etc. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure how well this translates to 'R' which I never used, but in Python this is how I would approach it:

```
lines = list()
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
      lines.append(line.split())
```

That will read everything in a python list. Lists are zero-based. To get the text column from the second line:

```
print lines[1][2]
```

The score for that line:

```
print lines[1][3]
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Panda's DataFrame, you can use the rpy2 library (from http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.rpy/1344):

```
import array
import rpy2.robjects as ro

d = dict(x = array.array('i', [1,2]), y = array.array('i', [2,3]))
dataf = ro.r['data.frame'](**d)
```

Answer (score 6):

One option that I've used in the past is `csv.DictReader`, which lets you reference data in a row by name (each row becomes a `dict`):

```
import csv
with open('data.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Output:

```
{'text': 'This is the text I need to read...', 'score': '88', 'id2': '889', 'id1': '123'}
{'text': 'This is the text I need to read...', 'score': '78', 'id2': '778', 'id1': '234'}
{'text': 'This is the text I need to read...', 'score': '91', 'id2': '667', 'id1': '345'}
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of R in python is Pandas

You initialise a DataFrame as below

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv("filename")

 print df.head()
```